# SQL GCP unnest data

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I have a table in GCP as

```
order_no  |  parameters.name  |  parameters.stringValue
  1             country               us
                 price                12
                device                ios
  2             country               gb
                 price                63
                device                android
  3             country               ca
                 price                45
                device                ios
```

I want to select all ios orders.
This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT *
FROM table,
UNNEST (parameters) as p
WHERE p.device = 'ios'
```

Comment: So, where is the actual problem ?

Comment: It's not p.device but p.stringValue to use

Comment: How do I select the column?

Answer (score 1):

**Posting this as a community wiki so others can benefit from it.**

---

As mentioned by guillaume blaquiere:

> It's not p.device but p.stringValue to use

---

```
SELECT *
FROM table,
UNNEST (parameters) as p
WHERE p.stringValue = 'ios'
```